# How can I detect when a player holds a tagged item? I just need to know the nbt for tagged items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My command is

```
execute at @a[ scores={fire_mage=1..},tag=mage:1b] run summon minecraft:fireball ^ ^1 ^1
```

However this command does not detect the tag and shows an error for tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For holding, there's a tag named `SelectedItem`, and you can use it in `/execute at @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{mage:1b}}}] run summon minecraft:fireball ^ ^1 ^1`